# Error 'too many output arguments' when Construct confusion matrix from 10-fold cross validation

Tags: matlab, confusion-matrix

This is my full code for kfold cross validation and confusion matrix. It can run perfectly before this and able to show the confusion matrix table also.

```
load('FruitData');
X = training;
Y = category;
Md1 = fitcknn(X,Y,'NumNeighbors',3,'distance','euclidean')
CVMd1 = crossval(Md1);
classError = kfoldLoss(CVMd1) 
oosLoss = kfoldLoss(CVMd1,'Mode','individual')

oofLabel = kfoldPredict(CVMd1); %returns class labels 
ConfMat = confusionmat(Y,oofLabel);
[n,p] = size(X);
isLabels = unique(Y);
nLabels = numel(isLabels);% Order of the group labels

% Convert the integer label vector to a class-identifier matrix.
[~,grpOOF] = ismember(oofLabel,isLabels);
oofLabelMat = zeros(nLabels,n);
idxLinear = sub2ind([nLabels n],grpOOF,(1:n)');
oofLabelMat(idxLinear) = 1; % Flags the row corresponding to the class
[~,grpY] = ismember(Y,isLabels);
YMat = zeros(nLabels,n);
idxLinearY = sub2ind([nLabels n],grpY,(1:n)');
YMat(idxLinearY) = 1;

figure;
plotconfusion(YMat,oofLabelMat);
```

But somehow when I run it today, it show some error like below:

What should I do?

```
    Error using grp2idx
    Too many output arguments.

    Error in confusionmat (line 168)
    [idx,gn,gl] = grp2idx([g;ghat]);

    Error in kfoldcv (line 16)
    ConfMat = confusionmat(Y,oofLabel);
```

Comment: Is it possible that you've got a function in the current working directory called `grp2idx` that's overshadowing the built-in function?

Comment: if that is the reason, so what should I do? @beaker

Comment: If you've created a function with the same name as a built-in function, you should rename your function (assuming it's a function you want to keep) or just delete it.

Comment: You can test this by typing `which grp2idx` in the MATLAB command window - on my system this returns `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\toolbox\stats\stats\grp2idx.m`. If the result you get doesn't look right for your platform and MATLAB version then you may have found the problem.

Comment: I just found my mistake, I've created a function with the same name as a built-in function like @beaker said. And the problem solved after I delete it. Thanks guys for your help